# Google App Engine - Is this just a fluke, or could changing the version of an app improve cold-start time?

Tags: java, google-app-engine

Here is the situation: I had an app with a cold start time of about 4 seconds.  I was trying to improve the cold start time by removing a bunch of libraries and code I didn't really need.  After doing that the cold start time was about 3 seconds latency, and 3 seconds CPU time used.

I changed the version number in appengine-web.xml, and nothing else.  And now I have two versions of my app that have the exact same code, up and running.

For cold starts, the newer version uses 1800ms to 1900ms in CPU time.

For cold starts, the older version uses 2400ms to 3000ms in CPU time.

The exact same jsp page from each version is requested to test the cold start time.  So far I have sampled 7 cold starts for each version.

Comment: When you have data showing a clear difference, the conclusion should probably be "there is a difference I hadn't thought of" rather than "the data must be wrong". We forget things (or analyze incorrectly) all the time but it's pretty hard to randomly get five data points on each side of a distribution.

Comment: @Jefromi Yep, I'm hoping someone can come up with some reason I hadn't thought of, or someone from Google can confirm that this could happen.

Comment: @Spines: That comment was directed in large part at Mimisbrunnr's assumption that it was a fluke because there was no obvious explanation. I just figured it was better placed as a global comment preventing more "it's just a fluke" answers.

Comment: you just missed today's IRC chat.  you could have asked the devs directly!

Comment: you've probably already checked this, but are both versions of your code using the same sdk?  ie, did you upload both of these versions recently?

Comment: @Peter yea they are both using the same sdk version.  Do you know if the sdk version makes a difference on production?  Because I have an old app running sdk version 1.2.6 and its loading request time is around 1.5 seconds.  And I haven't seen any loading requests that low since I switched to sdk 1.3.1, though it may be something else too. I asked this question about it (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2465730/does-the-google-app-engine-sdk-version-you-build-your-app-with-affect-anything-on)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

hmmm, I think it is possible that there is some kind of caching of the look of your application, since gae upload is basically differential update (you send only changed files).

If you posted many changes on one version id, it is possible that GAE has many snapshots of your code.

Thus, if you do big changes (this is my rule of thumb) you should always change the version of your application, just to be sure. Additional commits I use only for bug fixes, never for big refactorings/adding or removing JARs. I think you also at that point you have new logs and simply "refreshing installation" of your application so GAE can do some optimizations...

Agree?

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like a fluke, I don't see how changing the version number of your program could generate a change in speed. Unless there was a coincidental library update or some such.

Comment: Exact same code and libraries used, however the old version I had been developing on for over a month.  Maybe old libraries aren't cleaned up completely or something when you upload your app?

Comment: That's possible, I'd take both code basses, then guarantee they are running off the same libraries on the same machine and run some more testing. Something is obviously different because of the speed shift, but I still doubt it's version number.

Answer (score 0):

Could the version number be changing an execution path somewhere? Perhaps in the XML parser or data binding that happens before your app is running?