# Does the Google App Engine SDK version you build your app with affect anything on the production app engine?

Tags: java, google-app-engine

If I develop with version 1.2.6 of the App Engine SDK, once I publish to production will my app still be using version 1.2.6 of all of the libraries on the production app engine?  Or will it automatically use the latest version of the core app engine libraries?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It looks like it will continue to use the old libraries until you manually upgrade the libraries contained in your application. From the [**Google App Engine Java documentation**](http://code.google.com/appengine/docs/java/runtime.html):

> This API is represented by the
>   appengine-api-*.jar included with the
>   SDK (where * represents the version of
>   the API and the SDK). You select the
>   version of the API your application
>   uses by including this JAR in the
>   application's WEB-INF/lib/
>   directory. If a new version of the
>   Java runtime environment is released
>   that introduces changes that are not
>   compatible with existing apps, that
>   environment will have a new version
>   number. **Your application will
>   continue to use the previous version
>   until you replace the JAR with the new
>   version (from a newer SDK) and
>   re-upload the app.**

Comment: That quote is true for the api (appengine-api-*.jar), but the app engine sdk comes with tons of other libraries that don't fit the (appengine-api-*.jar) format.  Any idea about those other libraries?